# Why is v-model not binding data in IE11?

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, internet-explorer, vue.js

I have a straightforward set of fields with `v-model` attributes:

```
<input type="hidden" v-model="product.id" value="{{ $product[0]->id }}">
<select class="c-select" v-model="product.size" v-on:click="sizeSelected = true">
```

I use the data bound to `product` in a call to a Laravel controller which accesses my database. In all other browsers, this works perfectly. However, in IE, it simply fails to bind any data. The result is a null request is passed to the controller and an error is thrown in the back end.

Why is IE not binding the data?

Comment: `$product[0]-id` looks suspicious

Comment: which IE version you are talking about?